# Java: How to pass typed-array class as parameter?

Tags: java

I have some 3rd-party API with method `someFn(int code, int[] data)`.

How can I express types (particulary array-typed argument) outside API container (interface class) for usage in `Class.getMethod(name, Integer.class, ???.class);`? How can I describe argument of array type properly?

As far as I know, I may use workaround like, but is there a better way of doing this?

```java
class C { void f(int[] a) {} } }

C.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getParameterTypes()[0]
```

<sub>Thanks in advance</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int[].class` to get the class literal of `int []` and pass it to [`Class.getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29):

```
Class.getMethod(name, Integer.class, int[].class);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Class.getMethod(name, Integer.class, int[].class);
```

`int[]` is class and hence `int[].class` is a valid statement to refer int array class.